# singleton or class with static field

Tags: java

I have a class that looks like this

```
class FileProcessorContext {
    private static BufferedWriter fileWriter;
    static {
        createFile();
    }
    public static void writeToFile(...) {}
    public static synchronized void closeFile(...) {}
}
```

Can I create `FileProcessorContext` as singleton and use it, instead of this pseudo(it keeps some state)-utility class?

Comment: The most important different between a class with static methods and a singleton is that the singleton can have inheritance and can be passed around. If you're not doing that it doesn't really matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "the singleton can have inheritance"? A proper singleton type cannot be inherited as one could never instantiate a child class without​ destroying the singleton property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  could use a enum with a single enum value as each enum value is out of the box a singleton.
The enum could implement an interface to be testable and in order to be able to switch to another implementation if required :

```
public enum FileBufferedProcessorService implements FileProcessorService {

    SINGLETON;
    private BufferedWriter fileWriter;

    FileBufferedProcessorService(){  
       createFile();
   }
     ....

    public synchronized void writeToFile(...) {}
    public synchronized void closeFile(...) {}
}
```

And the interface :

```
public interface FileProcessorService {

    void writeToFile(...);

    void closeFile(...);

}
```

Comment: yup, I know about the singleton solution that Bloch used in the book. I was just curious where using utility class which has state and static method is worse than singleton

Comment: I would emphasize what @davidxxx wrote: "testable and in order to be able to switch to another implementation if required". In **this** meaning a utility class is worse than singleton.

Comment: oh I get it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I was not available. @Honza Zidek is totally right. Static methods are not designed to be naturally switched, injected with IOC or tested. So static methods should used only for utility tasks (formatting, simple conversion, etc...) where you don't care to isolate/switch the utility component.